# how to display jquery page using javascript?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

here is my problem, i call this method and what it does is

post some data on server using jQuery, i want to display page using result i recieve from server and quick thing
**loginSubmit() calls loginPostData** ,loginSubmit make a json object and pass it to loginPostData

here is the piece of code from javascript

```
function loginPostData(jsonRequest)
{
    $.post("http://localhost:8080/edserve/MobileServlet", 
            JSON.stringify( jsonRequest), 
            function(data) 
            {
                var obj = JSON.stringify(data);
                //var object = JSON.parse(json_text);
                //alert(obj);
                alert(obj);
                if(data.status=="success")
                {
                    //display main page
                                  //$('#mainMenu').show(); <-- this does not give desired result
                }
                else
                {
                    if(data.message=="user not verified")
                    {
                        //display verification page
                    }   
                    if(data.message=="no user exist with this usname")
                    {
                        //set focus to username
                        $("#username").focus();
                    }   
                }   
        }, "json");
}
```

and the page structure is like this

```
<div data-role="page" id="login">
    // other page content
            <div id="divrightButton">

            <!-- calling loginSubmit which calls loginPostData-->   
            <a class="bluebutton" href="#" onclick="loginSubmit(); return false;">Login</a>

            </div>
        </form>
</div>

<!--main page-->
<div data-role="page" id="mainMenu">

     Main menu
</div>
```

HOW TO SHOW MAIN MENU WHEN THERE IS SUCCESS, 
the entire code of html is in single file in different div's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code to redirect/display the particular div element

`$.mobile.changePage("#mainMenu",{allowSamePageTransition: true });`

and also download following css file, its a must for transitioning between pages/div elements

[jquery.mobile.transitions.css](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/ca9df1197a9748ee7448fb9b28c14c41d80d4601/themes/default/jquery.mobile.transitions.css)